# The encoding on my java files stopped working in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have been writing java in vs code for almost a year now with UTF-8 encoding without any problems.
I have been using Icelandic letters in my comments and to print to the console.
But now when I write them in new Java files, java won't accept them and changes them to �. I then checked my old java files, when I open them the encoding is fine, but as soon as I save the file the encoding changes.
It seems like this is only a problem with java files.
The files are fine in other editors like IntelliJ
Any idea on a solution for this?